# Validate phone numbers in c# (Console)

Tags: c#, console

Can I restrict the phone numbers in my console app without regular expressions?
I have this code, but it doesn´t work with international numbers, begining with 00.

```
   static public bool CheckPhoneNumb (string phoneNumber)
    {
        long lphoneNumber;
        return ((phoneNumber.Length >= 9) && phoneNumber.Length <= 15) &&
                (long.TryParse (phoneNumber, out lphoneNumber))) ? true : false;
    }
```

Thnks.

Comment: Phone number handling is complicated and the rules for what is/isn't allowed varies from application to application. You need to narrow down what you're having trouble with before you'll get much help.

Comment: You can restrict phone numbers in whatever way you choose. What criteria are you basing a phone number on? How do you know what a phone number looks like?

Comment: Why can't you use Regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to support worldwide calling, you will have a hard time doing so with regular expressions.

I would suggest the Google Phone Number Validation Library.

> Parsing/formatting/validating phone numbers for all countries/regions of the world.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

There's a C# port linked at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It is better than nothing, but it does a terrible job of validating US phone numbers.  Obviously incorrect phone numbers such as (312)811-1111 come up valid when they aren't, and can't be.

Answer (score 1):

International phone numbers don't begin with 00.  The 00 part is the code that you use in your part of the world to begin dialing the actual international number (which follows the 00).  That number changes from where you are dialing from.  For example, in the US, it is 011.  In Europe, it is 00.  Japan has a different code, and there are a few others.

Yes, you can restrict it without regular expressions, but you would probably find it easier to, and I would highly recommend you don't store your (or any) international access code with it, as it varies according to whom you display it to.

Comment: But people often put it in their local address book exactly that way.  The better way is often to use the + sign followed by the country code, though not all software and not all phones support that convention.

Comment: Yes, I would strip it before storing it however.  Accept garbage in, but don't allow garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you seek is rather more complex than you might think.

Often the number itself varies depending one the origin and destination locale as prefixes get added/removed.

What kind of phone numbers? NANP (North American Numbering Plan) or somewhere else?

The NANP, which covers the US, Canada, Mexico and the Carribean is described at http://www.nanpa.com/. For numbering plans in place around the world, a good place to start is at the World Telephone Numbering Guide at http://www.wtng.info/

Answer (score -1):

```
return ((phoneNumber.Length >= 9) && phoneNumber.Length <= 15) && phoneNumber.All(char.IsNumber);
```

Comment: So (232)888-8888 is invalid, while 999333444456 is valid?

Comment: except this would fail for numbers with extensions, which are generally in formats like `000-000-0000 x000`

Comment: You are assuming that the phone number in question is a us phone number. Of course this would not always work.

Comment: I realize this won't solve the problem the original poster asked for, for example, it only allows US phone numbers, and it uses regular expressions, but perhaps it could be a starting place.  This is the expression I use: ^(?:(?:(?:(?:\(([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\))|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})|(?:(?:(?:\((456|500|533|544|566|700|800|855|866|877|888|900)\))|(456|500|533|544|566|700|800|855|866|877|888|900))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)([2-9]\d{2}))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*e?x?t?\s*(\d{1,5}))?$